# How do I get my custom post type archive page to display my posts alphabetically?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called "career" and taxonomies setup for locations. My main careers page lists all each careers correctly and in alpha order. Here is my main query:

```
<?php    
  $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'career',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'posts_per_page' => 30, 
    'paged' => $page
  ));
?>
```

You can click on the location link (the taxonomy) for each career and you get an archive page that filters by that location. Now here's where I run into problems. Filtering works great but it reverts to the default post-date order. I want it to stay in alphabetical order. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the Wordpress docs on the matter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display), when you click the location link, you're winding up on a page based on a template that must not be using the same query as your main careers page, and you need to figure out what it is.

Alternatively, you can just create `taxonomy-location.php` based on the template for Careers, which sits at the top of the hierarchy for templates when showing taxonomy pages.